# Qual a diferença entre revalidate() e repaint()?

Tags: java, swing

Quando se trabalha com swing, geralmente chamamos um destes métodos após alguma alteração em componentes da tela. Mas afinal, qual a diferença entre se utilizar [`repaint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint--) ou [`revalidate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate--)? Em que situação devo utilizar um ou outro, ou até mesmo os dois juntos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resumidamente você deve utilizar os dois.

O `repaint()` alerta o Swing que alguma área da tela está inadequada, "suja". É necessário para apagar a imagem de componentes filhos antigos removidos pelo `removeAll()` por exemplo.

O `revalidate()` recalcula o layout através do layout manager. Normalmente utilizado quando se adiciona componentes no painel. Isso faz com que os componentes **filhos** do painel se "reposicionem", mas não o painel em si.
Esse método é chamado em [casos específicos](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#triggers).

Lembrando que `revalidate()` é a chamada do método `invalidate()` em todos os componentes do conteiner, que os marca como inválidos, e logo após o `validate()`. Isso chama o método `layoutComponents()` do layout manager. Caso seja necessário uma mudança no layout, o `repaint()` é chamado.