# Dúvida em relação aos métodos dispose() e repaint()

Tags: java, swing, java2d

Qual a função dos métodos `.dispose()` e `repaint()` no uso do Graphics no Java?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre revalidate() e repaint()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224861/28595)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estiver se referindo ao método [`dispose()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose--) da classe `Graphics`, conforme dito na própria documentação, ele serve para liberar os recursos do sistema que esta classe utiliza quando você cria uma instância dela.

Pense que, já que esta classe tem uma importância base na criação de tudo que se vê na tela, ela pode consumir muitos recursos do sistema, além de ter várias instâncias associadas. Ainda conforme a documentação, o coletor de lixo da JVM geralmente consegue lidar com isso, mas dando `dispose()`, você consegue garantir com um pouco mais de eficiência que estes recursos utilizados serão, de fato, liberados. Lembrando que uma instância de `Graphics` não poderá mais ser utilizada após este método ser chamado.

Já o método `repaint()`, como já explicado [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224881/28595), tem por finalidade avisar que a tela precisa ser redesenhada, possivelmente por alguma área ter sofrido alguma alteração, e assim a tela é toda redesenhada e é exibidas com as atualizações feitas nela.