# Distribuição de componentes em GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout

O exemplo abaixo tem um `GroupLayout` que contém dois elementos, uma barra customizada de pesquisa e filtragem (`JPanelSearchAndFilter`) e um `JScrollPane`.

Quando ele é executado e em seguida a janela é maximizada você pode observar que esses dois elementos estão distribuídos igualmente na tela.

Ao selecionar um item qualquer na combo box, a tela se enche de linhas de texto e a barra de pesquisa e filtragem passa a ocupar um tamanho menor na tela, dando espaço às linhas de texto.

Gostaria de saber como fazer para deixar essa barra nesse tamanho menor desde o começo da execução. De preferência sem usar um `BorderLayout` para isso.

Pensei em setar o tamanho do `JScrollPane` ou preenchê-lo com itens invisíveis, mas isso me parece gambiarra. Acredito que seja possível uma solução utilizando *layout managers*.

**GroupPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class GroupPanel extends JPanel implements Listener   {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanelSearchAndFilter jPanelSearchAndFilter = new JPanelSearchAndFilter();
    private JPanel jPanelListaOrders = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane jScrollPaneOrders = new JScrollPane(jPanelListaOrders);

    public GroupPanel() {

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanelMainLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);

        jPanelMainLayout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanelMainLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanelMainLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanelMainLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jPanelSearchAndFilter)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPaneOrders))
                        ));

        jPanelMainLayout.setVerticalGroup(jPanelMainLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanelMainLayout.createSequentialGroup().addGroup(
                        jPanelMainLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanelMainLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jPanelSearchAndFilter)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPaneOrders)))));

        this.setLayout(jPanelMainLayout);

        jPanelListaOrders.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(254, 254, 254));
        jPanelListaOrders.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(jPanelListaOrders, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        jPanelSearchAndFilter.setListener(this);
    }

    private static void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("GroupPanel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(f.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        f.add(new GroupPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                display();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(String event) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(event + " " + i);
            label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 60));
            jPanelListaOrders.add(label);
        }

        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

**JPanelSearchAndFilter.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JPanelSearchAndFilter extends JPanel {

    private static final String [] ORDER_STATUSES = {
            "Todos",
            "Novos",
            "Confirmados",
            "Prontos/Enviados",
            "Entregues",
            "Cancelados"
            };

    private Listener listener = null;

    public JPanelSearchAndFilter() {

        setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        searchField = new JTextField("Pesquisar");
        searchField.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        searchField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        searchField.setToolTipText("Pesquisar");
        add(searchField);
        searchField.setColumns(10);

        // Cria um espaço vazio de tamanho fixo entre searchField e filterComboBox.
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, 0)));

        ComboBoxModel<String> filterComboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(ORDER_STATUSES);
        JComboBox<String> filterComboBox = new JComboBox<>(filterComboModel);
        filterComboBox.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        filterComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

        filterComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
                JPanelSearchAndFilter.this.listener.onEvent((String)itemEvent.getItem());
            }
        });

        add(filterComboBox);
    }

    public void setListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField searchField;
}
```

**Listener.java**

```
public interface Listener {
    public void onEvent(String event);
}
```

Comment: Esse grouppanel é realmente necessario?

Comment: @ArticunoL Desculpe a minha inexperiência. Ele poderia ser um JPanel (na verdade é um), foi a forma que encontrei para transpor o código da aplicação em que estou trabalhando para o exemplo. Acredito que é um elemento-raiz da estrutura que é necessário sim. O que você pensou?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O layout manager que está utilizando([`GroupLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html)) trabalha com valores relativos, e você acaba por misturar outro layout(`BoxLayout`) por cima que também trabalha com valores relativos para definir a distribuição dos componentes na tela, mas o primeiro acaba prevalecendo. O problema é que, ao revalidar o painel, ele entende que precisa dispor mais espaço para a lista e reduz o tamanho do outro painel com o campo de texto.

Embora seja um layout manager bem robusto, `Grouplayout` é extremamente complexo para se usar, tanto que geralmente é usado apenas pelas engines de geração de telas de IDE's como o caso do netbeans.

A solução do problema que encontrei consistiu em remover completamente o `GroupLayout` e usar o [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), que apesar de também trabalhar com valores relativos, ele define melhor a distribuição dos componentes na tela, distribuindo em 5 regioes fixas. Como você quer que o painel de pesquisa fique na parte superior e o painel de lista na parte posterior ao painel de pesquisa, basta definir conforme abaixo sua classe `GroupPanel`:

```
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    this.add(jPanelSearchAndFilter, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(jScrollPaneOrders, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Se não houver mais nenhuma região definida, o `JSCrollPane` irá ocupar todo o restante das regiões do `Borderlayout`, a partir da região definida.

Outro detalhe que modifiquei também é o `repaint()`, uma vez que, conforme [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224881/28595), o mesmo já é invocado internamente quando você executa o `revalidate()` para redesenhar a tela.

O código ficou da seguinte forma:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class GroupPanel extends JPanel implements Listener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanelSearchAndFilter jPanelSearchAndFilter = new JPanelSearchAndFilter();
    private JPanel jPanelListaOrders = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane jScrollPaneOrders = new JScrollPane(jPanelListaOrders);

    public GroupPanel() {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(jPanelSearchAndFilter, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(jScrollPaneOrders, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jPanelListaOrders.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(254, 254, 254));
        jPanelListaOrders.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(jPanelListaOrders, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        jPanelSearchAndFilter.setListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("GroupPanel");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new GroupPanel());
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(String event) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(event + " " + i);
            label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 60));
            jPanelListaOrders.add(label);
        }

        revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Uma dúvida, qual é o problema do JFrame ser estático?

Comment: @Piovezan pesquisando aqui, percebi que estava equivocado, não vaza da EDT porque a jvm já inicia de forma automática dentro dela quando vc da `setVisible()`. Mas futuramente se for adicionar operações multithreading, pode dar alguns probleminhas com os listeners, então, pra evitar problemas, e melhor deixar tudo a cargo da EDT mesmo.